# set content of tinymce with a string of html

Tags: html, jsf, httpresponse, tinymce-4

I have a JSF Renderer that uses responsewriter to generate a jsf page .
In this class I create a String that contains html code , something like this :

```
 String s = "<b>hello</b> <i>world</i>" .
```

when I create a tinymce editor and set the value of it with responsewriter like this :

```
   responseWriter.writeText(value, null);
```

it show exactly the same String (showing HTML tag) instead of HTML format of it.

I know it's Wrong to use writeText for writing HTML but I don't  know what to use instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I solved my problem in this way :
I set the value in a hidden like this :

```
    responseWriter.startElement("input", null);
            responseWriter.writeAttribute("type", "hidden", null);
            responseWriter.writeAttribute("id", "tinymcevalue" , null);
            responseWriter.writeAttribute("name", "required-" + filerRichTextEditor.getSchemaName(), null);


            responseWriter.writeAttribute("value", getDocumentFieldValue(filerUIComponent.getSchemaName()), null);
            responseWriter.endElement("input");
```

and then I set it in my JSF :

```
   tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(document.getElementById("tinymcevalue").value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setContent.

```
responseWriter.setContent(s);
```

More information here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.setContent